# How to fix error for mock object not being able to work as concrete class?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I have a service for which I want to write tests. The service expects an concrete implementation of a class:

```
MyService
{

    public function doSth(MyObject $object) {
         ...
    }

}
```

In my test file I create the mock like so:

```
public function getMyObjectMock()
{
    $mock = $this->getMock('My\SomeOtherBundle\Entity\MyObject');
    return $mock;
}
```

In the test I will create an mock via into the service. I will get this strange error message:

```
Argument 1 passed to My\Bundle\Services\Service::doSth()
must be an instance of My\Bundle\Entity\MyObject,
instance of Mock_MyObject_974a63e9 given,
called in My/Bundle/Tests/Services/ServiceTest.php on line 47 and defined
```

How to fix that? Can I only declare interfaces in other classes? Or can I make the mock object look like the concrete class?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was within a wrong declared fully qualified class name which wasn't obvious from the error message to me in the `$this->getMock()` method.

In terms of the example it should have been:

```
public function getMyObjectMock()
{
    $mock = $this->getMock('My\Bundle\Entity\MyObject');
    return $mock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need use `setMockClassName`:

```
...
$this->getMockBuilder(''My\Bundle\Entity\MyObject')
  ->setMockClassName('MyObject')
...
```

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#test-doubles.mock-objects